# Python parser comments from channel post

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, telegram, telegram-bot

## I was doing my parser bot to get random messages from comments under telegram post

```
import aiogram
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

# Создаем экземпляр бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Словарь для хранения URL пользователей
user_urls = {}


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Введите URL, чтобы получить случайный комментарий.")


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.startswith('https://t.me/'))
async def process_url(message: types.Message):
    url = message.text
    comments = get_comments(url)
    
    if comments:
        random_comment = random.choice(comments)
        await message.reply(f"Случайный комментарий:\n{random_comment}")
    else:
        await message.reply("Комментарии не найдены.")
    
    # Сохраняем URL пользователя
    user_urls[message.from_user.id] = url
    
    # Просим пользователя ввести новый URL или команду /start
    await message.reply("Введите новый URL или отправьте /start для начала заново.")


def get_comments(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            comments = soup.find_all('div', class_='tgme_widget_message_text')
            comment_texts = [comment.get_text() for comment in comments]
            return comment_texts
        else:
            return []
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

I dont get comments from url link and any of it. I want bot to reply message in chat with him ( user and bot). So i need from bot to resend message with files and e.t.c

Everything> nothing helps